# How to get session in bot framework trigger event (Proactive template)?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

This is the trigger event of a bot with Proactive template.

```
bot.on('trigger', function (message) {
    // handle message from trigger function
    var queuedMessage = message.value;
    var reply = new builder.Message()
        .address(queuedMessage.address)
        .text('Your order is placed, ref: ' + queuedMessage.orderRef);
    bot.send(reply);
    //save this orderRef to session userData
    //session.userData.lastOrderRef = queuedMessage.orderRef;
});
```

Here I need to save the `orderRef` to corresponding user `session`. How to get the `session` in trigger event?

Comment: Have you looked over https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages/startNewDialog ? Specifically, the botadapter.js loadSession

Comment: @EricDahlvang Thanks for the link, that solves the problem.

Comment: @EricDahlvang, I'm also facing the same issue. That link seems to be not working, Can you provide a solution here ?

Comment: @Venkat No idea about whether these API's are changed or not - Try https://gist.github.com/sreejith-ms/78e91030d498855130aa54ea6f9322c6

Comment: @rebornx, Thanks

Comment: You can also find an older version of botadapter here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages/blob/master/node/startNewDialog/botadapter.js

Comment: Shame that the answer for this question is hidden in a form of a link only comment, which returns "not found" as of today.